# the color of the icon handler on the main page on different pages

Tags: reactjs, colors, menu, icons, handler

please help. I need to make the color of the icon handler on the main page to white and on the other pages of the site to keep the dark as it is now.
on the https://github.com/react-component/drawer .
if i change the color in the css file, it will be the same on all pages. but on my site the first page is dark and the others light. therefore, on the main page, the item to open the menu is not visible. and on the rest normally visible.
https://codesandbox.io/s/9z3zrz3814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs on github I see component drawer accept a props "prefixCls" where you can manage different classes based on props instead of rely on a single css class.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console,react/no-multi-comp */
import Drawer from 'rc-drawer';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';


const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;
const MenuItemGroup = Menu.ItemGroup;

ReactDom.render((
  <div>
    <Drawer width="20vw" prefixCls={myCondition ? myClass : myOtherClass}>
      <Menu
        style={{ height: '200%' }}
        defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
        defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
        mode="inline"
      >
        <SubMenu
          key="sub1"
          title={<span><Icon type="mail" /><span>Navigation One</span></span>}
        >
          <MenuItemGroup key="g1" title="Item 1">
            <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
          </MenuItemGroup>
          <MenuItemGroup key="g2" title="Item 2">
            <Menu.Item key="3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
          </MenuItemGroup>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu
          key="sub2"
          title={<span><Icon type="appstore" /><span>Navigation Two</span></span>}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="5">Option 5</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="6">Option 6</Menu.Item>
          <SubMenu key="sub3" title="Submenu">
            <Menu.Item key="7">Option 7</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="8">Option 8</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu
          key="sub4"
          title={<span><Icon type="setting" /><span>Navigation Three</span></span>}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="9">Option 9</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="10">Option 10</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="11">Option 11</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="12">Option 12</Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
      </Menu>
    </Drawer>
    <div
      style={{
        width: '100%', height: 667, background: '#fff000',
        color: '#fff', textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: '667px',
      }}
    >
      内容区块
    </div>
  </div>), document.getElementById('__react-content'));
```

Comment: I've update the example, the condition will be based on your app structure, you can check for a route path or for a props from the container

Comment: the component itself does not manage inline styles but you can do it in a condition on your own. Keeping styles in a separate css file is better, IMHO

Comment: You CAN do it with inline styles. The issue lacks of complete scenario to work with, there are multiple ways to achieve this, and none of them unconfortable. You have to get more used to react patterns and you must be able to recognize an antipattern.

Comment: Take a look at styled-components